# Choosing between two boolean methods when setting up a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been scratching heads for hours now, trying to figure out how to do this properly. I'm building a form, and want the user to choose between two options: `"Lemonade" OR "Pepsi"`.

I've got `"Lemonade"` and `"Pepsi"` as **two booleans** in my database, and looking for a way to make the second checkbox be uncheckable when the first one is, OR have a drop down menu selecting only one of them (where `checked = true`). 
In other words, when showing a `"Drink list"`, I want it to say `Pepsi = true/Lemonade=false` or vice versa. I've tried using validations, but can't seem to get this working. Any good ideas?

Hope the question was understandable.

FYI: New to RoR.

Comment: Just as a side note, I would simply say that it seems like bad design, what if you want to add a new type of drink ? You'll need to update your table schema. Whereas if you had an association like : "a drink belongs_to a type of drink" & "a type of drink has many drinks" then it would much simpler to maintain, and creating the form would also be way simpler

Comment: You're absolutely right, though I can't understand why associations would make it  easier creating the form - could you elaborate?

Comment: have a look at formtastic for instance this section particularly : https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic#it%E2%80%99s-awesome-because%E2%80%A6 everything will be automatically done for you in the form (almost) :)

Comment: did you manage to make things work or do you sill need help ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a default value when create boolean column, it will have default value is `Lemonade` or `Pepsi`. Then in your view, you will display the checkbox with value which different default value, example:

If your default value is `Lemonade`, you will display checkbox with value `Pepsi` on your form. So, if user don't check, default option user selected is `Lemonade`, and if user check `Pepsi`, then you will save that option. You can put checkbox with a label something like: "If you don't check Pepsi, your option will be Lemonade" . I think that will be solution for you in this case.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but as I want this to be scalable I can't settle with just two options, and as pjam points out, this would make it a PITA to add more drinks. I'm utterly grateful anyway!